# Start new activity on android?

Tags: android, class, button, android-intent, android-activity

How can i start the activity starting with this code?

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_simple)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startGraphActivity(SimpleGraph.class);
            }
 });
```

of course `SimpleGraph.class` is the new activity.. Actually this code assume needs a `startGraphActivity` class to run. I would not use this class. I tried to write

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_simple)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SimpleGraph.class));
                }
     });
```

But when i click the button the application crash. Any help?

Comment: Have you declared the Activity in the AndroidManifest?

Comment: Is `SimpleGraph` activity defined in your Manifest file.? Post Logcat traces for more insight...

Comment: SimpleGraph.class is an activity declared in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: you should read the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Comment: Which exception/error did you get?

Comment: I have declared the activity in the manifest yes..is it my code wrong?i mean, the code with intent..

Comment: @David_D, what's the error your getting?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to :

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.___);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub




        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will work properly but you must add new class in manifest file where you want     to go through intent

```
         Button btn1;
          btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_simple);

          btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent it=new Intent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SimpleGraph.class)) ;   
            startActivity(it);
            }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

It may because you did not declare SimpleGraph in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Please make sure you have something like this in you manifest file

```
    <activity android:name=".SimpleGraph" />
```

Please see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Declaring) for more information.

Comment: he says he has declared activity ! irrelevant answer !

Comment: I'm sorry but I answered this before he said he has declared activity.